# Error on configuring Ruby Installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I've been digging through StackOverflow for an answer, but after three days of failure I gave up installing Ruby.

Currently I have installed:

1. Ruby (stock)
2. RVM
3. The Ruby installer from http://railsinstaller.org/

I am getting an error during the configuration. I already tried switching from SMF to Homebrew but that was no good.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --prefix=/Users/Unwired/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libxml2:/usr/local/opt/libxslt:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl:/usr/local/opt/sqlite --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
please read /Users/Unwired/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/1366883126_configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

I am really excited to start learning RoR but installing it is a pain.

Comment: If you don't have Ruby installed, I'm going to assume you don't have any Ruby experience. And, if you have no Ruby experience, I will *STRONGLY* recommend that you hold off trying to learn Rails. Rails uses deep Ruby magic to accomplish what it does, and, as a result much of what Rails does will be unfathomable to you. You'd do better to work with regular Ruby for a while, learn Sinatra and Padrino and do some small web apps with them, then move to Rails. That will give you a gradual learning curve, instead of slamming you head-on into Rail's learning curve, which would be more like a cliff.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Download your Rails installer from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ along with the DevKit.
2. Install Ruby.
3. Create a directory and extract the DevKit on `C:`, i.e., `C:\DevKit`.
4. Copy the path of Devkit to your `Environment Variables > Path` i.e., `C:\DevKit\bin;`.
5. Open `cmd` and type the following:

```
ruby dk.rb
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb install
```

1. Open another `cmd` and type `gem install rails`.
2. Install MySQL by typing: `gem install mysql`.

NOTE: Make sure you copy the path of Ruby to `Environment Variables > Path`. There is a selection on installing Ruby on rails there.

Comment: Hi Newbie,

Thank you also for the response, I am running Ruby on Mac. 

It is fix now..:)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Linux environment?
If so, follow the instructions in "[here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm)".

Comment: Hi Rony,

Thank you for your response,

I use Mac 10.8.3. After dealing with errors I tried to clean up my system, run fix permissions.

Reinstalled the RubyInstaller and RVM, I was able to install now either from terminal or RubyInstaller.

Currently running on Ruby 1.9.3-p392.

I can start now my RoR tutorials..

Cheers,

Patrick